# What this code "obj && obj.myFunction();" does in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m working on a project and I saw that at the end of some functions is called a jquery deferred object like this:

```
obj && obj.resolve();
```

What is the purpose of the `&&`? And what is the purpose of the self placed object in the begining (`obj`) ?

First I thought that calling like that is something like this:

if `obj` exists --> then call that function (`resolve`)...but I`ve tested the code with a simple object and it throws an error:

```
var b = {
    a:function(){alert('ok')}
};

a && a.a(); // ReferenceError: a is not defined

b && b.a(); // works...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is saying 'if `obj` is intantiated and is not null, call `obj.resolve()`'.

It works due to Javascript treating `0`, `null` and `undefined` as `false`, and any other value as `true`.

Comment: but if I call a && a.a(); // ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: `a` is a property of `b`, so can only be accessed via it's parent object. Also `a` has no child property named `a`.

Answer (score 3):

It's using `&&` as a "guard". It's basically checking if `obj` exists before doing something with it.

Explanation: Anything `false`, `null`, `undefined`, empty string, number zero are categorized as "falsy values". Anything other than those are "truthy values".

Operators like `&&` evaluate left to right. If the value on the left for `&&` is truthy, it tries to evaluate the one on the right. In this case, if `obj` is truthy, it evaluates `obj.resolve()`, basically executing it.

Comment: ReferenceError: a is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It is a shorthand for

```
if (obj) {
    obj.resolve();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(obj) {
}
```

is a check if obj is not undefined.

```
&&
```

means if the first expression is false (ie: if the obj is undefined in your case) dont bother checking the second argument which in your case is `obj.resolve();`

It prevents you from calling a method on obj which crashes if obj is `undefined`